# How can $|\mathbb{N}| = |\mathbb{Z}|$?

Tags: infinity

I have seen proofs of a bijection $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}$ where

$$f(n) = \begin{cases}
    \frac{n}{2} & n\text{ is even} \\
    -\frac{n + 1}{2} & \text{else}
\end{cases}$$

This shows that $\mathbb{Z}$ is countably infinite, that is, $f$ is one-to-one. We can also see that $f$ is onto. Therefore $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ have the same number of elements.

But at the same time, we have $\mathbb{N} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$. To show $\mathbb{N}$ is a proper subset of $\mathbb{Z}$, it would suffice to show that $\mathbb{Z}$ contains at least one element that $\mathbb{N}$ does not. Notice $-1 \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $-1 \notin \mathbb{N}$, so $\mathbb{N} \subset \mathbb{Z}$ and thus $|\mathbb{N}| < |\mathbb{Z}|$.

I assume this has something to with the fact that these are infinite sets, but I still can't put my finger on exactly why this can happen. If I could have some help understanding why this can happen, that would be great.

Comment: In fact, this is one of the mathematical definitions of infinite: 'can be put into 1:1 correspondence with a proper subset of itself'. One search phrase that might get you some helpful information is _Hilbert Hotel_.

Comment: $A \subset B$ (proper inclusion) only tells you $|A| \le |B|$. You can still have $|A| = |B|$.

Comment: The principle that $A\subsetneq B\implies\vert A\vert<\vert B\vert$, while absolutely true for finite sets, is not true for infinite sets; indeed, that's really their defining feature. It might help to go back and see the proof of that "obvious principle" for finite sets (specifically: show that if $A\subsetneq B$ and $A,B$ are finite then there is no injection of $B$ into $A$). It's surprisingly nontrivial!

Comment: @NoahSchweber That sounds like an interesting and helpful proof to see. Do you have a link by chance?

Comment: @epsilon-emperor This is only with infinite sets, correct? I don't see how this couldn't be the case with finite sets.

Comment: @Justin Yes, equality is possible **only if** $A$ and $B$ both are infinite. $|A| \le |B|$ holds **generally**, regardless of what $A$ and $B$ are.

Comment: "In mathematics you don't understand things.  You just get used to them."  --[John von Neumann](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/John_von_Neumann)

Comment: Think as to *why* is *seems* intuitive that a proper subset should be smaller than the super element.  It probably is because a proper subset should have fewer elements so it'd be smaller.  But why would a proper subset having fewer elements mean a set is smaller? Well if it has fewer it can't have as many... but how many *do* they have. They both have infinite so taking elements away won't *reduce* anything.  Missing elements only make a set smaller if there aren't enough other elements to make up for the missing elements.  But if the sets are *infinite* there's no shortage of elements.

Comment: " it would suffice to show that Z contains at least one element that N does not."  But that would only suffice if we assume $|\mathbb Z| - 1 < |\mathbb Z|$.  It is true that $\mathbb N$ does not contain $-1$.  So wherease $\mathbb Z$ will have an infinite number of elements, then $\mathbb N$ can only have..... infinity - 1?? ... this is really a *bad* way of thinking about bout if $|\mathbb N| = \infty$ then $\mathbb \{-n|n\in\mathbb Z\}$ is alse $\infty$.  And $\mathbb Z$ is both those sets and $0$.  So $|\mathbb Z|$ ought to be $2\infty + 1$. But is $2\infty + 1$ any bigger than $\infty$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's consider an example that is a bit easier to deal with:
\begin{align}
A &= \{1,2,3,4,\dots\}, \\
B &= \{0,1,2,3,\dots\}.
\end{align}
It's easy to see that $A\subsetneq B$ and yet $A\to B, k \mapsto k-1$ is a bijection.

The conclusion that $|A|<|B|$ doesn't work for infinite sets, since there are always elements to "fill the gaps". In this example, removing $0$ from $B$ you get a gap at $0$, but $1$ can fill that gap. Now there's a gap at $1$, but $2$ can fill that gap, … Since this "gap filling process" never ends, there is no gap that can't be filled and we get $|A|=|B|$.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. This made it very easy to visualize.

Answer (score 0):

In fact,  it can be shown that for a set $S $, being infinite,  or of infinite cardinality,  is equivalent to the having the property of being in bijection with a proper subset $P\subsetneq S $.

Of special interest is the (Hilbert's hotel) shifting function, $f(x)=x+1$ from the whole numbers to the naturals.

Answer (score 0):

> Therefore $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ have the same number of elements.

Wrong. They have the same *cardinality*. But it has nothing to do with the number of elements.

If we compare their *numerocities*, then $n(\mathbb{N})=\frac{n(\mathbb{Z})}2-\frac12$